# access 2d List parameters

Tags: scala

I have a 2d list

```
List("iii"->3,"v"->5)
```

I want to access JUST the "iii" part of the list.

I tried

```
res0(0)(0)
```

but to no avail.

Can someone help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have a 2d list

No, you don't. You have a list of tuples.

So if you know you want the first element of the first tuple of the list

```
 rest(0)._1               //> res0: String = iii
```

or to get the second element

```
 rest(0)._2               //> res1: Int = 3
```